# nodejs sequelize join query

Tags: node.js, join, orm, sequelize.js

Suppose i have two models

```
var A = db.seq.define('A',{
    id1: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    id2: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
    count: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER},
});

var b = db.seq.define("b",{
    id1: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER },
    id2: { type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER },
    name: { type: db.Sequelize.STRING},
});

A.hasMany(B, {foreignKey: 'id1'})
B.belongsTo(A, {foreignKey: 'id1'})

A.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: B,
        where: { B.id2: { $eq:A.id2 } }
    }]
})
```

Its possible to make that kind of query?

How can i update my model to specify some other condition on the join sentence or should i move the check to the query where clause?

Some example will be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
A.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: B,
        where: { id2: sequelize.col('A.id2') }
    }]
})
```

id2 will automatically reference B.

Comment: i test that theory maybe i did something wrong but the query its not working https://gist.github.com/bitgandtter/ef94e636579251974b51

Answer (score 0):

Currently Jan Aagaard Meier's answer is not fully working
I have found out that id2 is not recognized in the actual query.
For example the query

```
A.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: B,
        where: { id2: sequelize.col('A.id2') }
    }]
})
```

should recognize as inner join on 'A'.'PrimaryKey' = 'B'.'ForeignKey' and id2 = 'A'.'id2'
but somehow sequelize does not add up the left side so it ignores as
'A'.'PrimaryKey' = 'B'.'ForeignKey' and 'A'.'id2'

so query is not working
I've done the raw query that is printed when sequelize is executed and found out what was wrong.
Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

found the answer

```
A.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: B,
        where: { sequelize.col('A.id2), "=", sequelize.col('B.id2') }
    }]
})
```

This works fine for me. Hope this works well for you